# Exclude a line of text in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, pstricks, framed

I have this problem: inside a framebox there is a line of text which should not be a part of the tabular enviromnent because it widens the first tab.
Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-node,pstricks-add,amsmath}
%\usepackage{a lot of other packages}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](18,16)
\rput[Bc](9,8)
{\psframebox{\begin{tabular}{lll}
\underline{LongTextWhichInterferesWithTheTabs}\\
\\
$1$ & = & $A$ \\
$2$ & = & $B$ \\
$3$ & = & $C$ \\
$4$ & = & $D$ \\
$5$ & = & $E$ \\
\end{tabular}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way i can exclude the long underlined text from the tabular environment?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you clarify, where you want the text (one line, multi-lines). What's the problem putting the text outside (e.g. with inside `\parbox` within `\psframebox`) or using `\multicolumn`?

Comment: Hello Heiko! \multicolumn worked fine! Thank you for helping!